# File path with Unicode characters in Rscript.exe

Tags: r, svg, unicode, filesystems, rscript

I'm trying to save an SVG image to a file path containing Unicode characters. For example:

```
n = c(2, 3, 5)
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df = data.frame(n, s, b)

svg("c:/נועם/plots.svg")
plot(df)
dev.off()
```

Running this with Rscript.exe fails with the following error:

> Error in plot.new() : cairo error 'error while writing to output stream'

How can I make it work?

Comment: Looks like a Windows issue.

Comment: I would suggest not creating directory names in Hebrew in the first place. From my experience, working solely in English is the safest practice in order to avoid such and many other potential issues in general.

Comment: Also, see what happens when you do `normalizePath("c:/נועם/plots.svg")`

Comment: Hebrew was just given as an example. The script attempts to write to the user local folder (c:/users/<username>), and when the account username contain Unicode characters, I hit this bug.

Comment: @NoamBehar as a Sysadmin I will back up David's advice, don't use anything else than ascii letters. User names with unicode will lead to problems, home dirs are a pain to manage, permissions on NTFS will sometimes hang, etc. To fix your script, write elsewhere than user's home. If security/permissions are an issue, manage them instead of relying on a 'should be' state of the file at end as it can't be guaranteed in anyway.

Comment: I second the motion that is an OS bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can set working directory to the directory with Hebrew name than save svg file. Please see the code below:

```
n <- c(2, 3, 5)
s <- c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
b <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df <- data.frame(n, s, b)
setwd("C:\\נועם\\")
svg("plots.svg")
plot(df)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but I think that wrapping the path in `enc2native()` function normally solves encoding issues under Windows to my experience. In your case you should try

```
svg(enc2native("c:/נועם/plots.svg"))
```